# Fedora transaction test error on dnf update: file "conflicts"

Tags: fedora, dnf, software-updates

I am trying to update Fedora using `sudo dnf update`. It lists the packages to be updated, downloads them, but then fails with this message:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/bin/coredumpctl from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-veritysetup-generator from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-binfmt.service from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-homed.service from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-homed from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-portabled from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-veritysetup from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/org.freedesktop.portable1.5.gz from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-coredump.8.gz from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.home1.policy from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.portable1.policy from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
```

I tried googling but I am at a loss here (I am not an expert). I noticed no other issue or problem with the system so I don't know where this new problem comes from.
Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I tried to do `sudo dnf clean all` and then `sudo dnf update`, but this didn't help. I post the full output below.

Then as suggested I tried `sudo dnf upgrade --advisory=FEDORA-2022-1bf06aa328` and the output of that is:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:03 ago on Sat 23 Apr 2022 03:59:43 PM CEST.
No security updates needed, but 97 updates available
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

The output from `sudo dnf update` is below:

```
Fedora 35 - x86_64                              6.4 MB/s |  79 MB     00:12    
Fedora 35 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64        4.1 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora Modular 35 - x86_64                      2.0 MB/s | 3.3 MB     00:01    
Fedora 35 - x86_64 - Updates                    3.3 MB/s |  29 MB     00:08    
Fedora Modular 35 - x86_64 - Updates            1.7 MB/s | 2.9 MB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Free                 2.0 MB/s | 934 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Free - Updates       1.2 MB/s | 401 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Nonfree              353 kB/s | 239 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Nonfree - Updates    345 kB/s | 100 kB     00:00    
skype (stable)                                   26 kB/s | 5.2 kB     00:00    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sat 23 Apr 2022 03:59:43 PM CEST.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                            Arch   Version               Repo      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel                             x86_64 5.16.20-200.fc35      updates   86 k
 kernel-core                        x86_64 5.16.20-200.fc35      updates   46 M
 kernel-modules                     x86_64 5.16.20-200.fc35      updates   51 M
 kernel-modules-extra               x86_64 5.16.20-200.fc35      updates  3.3 M
Upgrading:
 at                                 x86_64 3.2.5-3.fc35          updates   61 k
 cups                               x86_64 1:2.3.3op2-17.fc35    updates  1.3 M
 cups-client                        x86_64 1:2.3.3op2-17.fc35    updates   71 k
 cups-filesystem                    noarch 1:2.3.3op2-17.fc35    updates   14 k
 cups-filters                       x86_64 1.28.14-1.fc35        updates  770 k
 cups-filters-braille               x86_64 1.28.14-1.fc35        updates   38 k
 cups-filters-libs                  x86_64 1.28.14-1.fc35        updates  136 k
 cups-ipptool                       x86_64 1:2.3.3op2-17.fc35    updates  3.9 M
 cups-libs                          x86_64 1:2.3.3op2-17.fc35    updates  265 k
 dhcp-client                        x86_64 12:4.4.3-2.fc35       updates  799 k
 dhcp-common                        noarch 12:4.4.3-2.fc35       updates  126 k
 distribution-gpg-keys              noarch 1.68-1.fc35           updates  356 k
 ffmpeg-libs                        x86_64 4.4.2-1.fc35          rpmfusion-free-updates
                                                                          8.4 M
 firefox                            x86_64 99.0.1-1.fc35         updates  104 M
 fwupd                              x86_64 1.7.7-1.fc35          updates  1.9 M
 fwupd-plugin-flashrom              x86_64 1.7.7-1.fc35          updates   42 k
 fwupd-plugin-modem-manager         x86_64 1.7.7-1.fc35          updates   71 k
 fwupd-plugin-uefi-capsule-data     x86_64 1.7.7-1.fc35          updates  2.1 M
 gdisk                              x86_64 1.0.9-1.fc35          updates  244 k
 gegl04                             x86_64 0.4.36-1.fc35         updates  3.0 M
 gzip                               x86_64 1.10-6.fc35           updates  149 k
 imath                              x86_64 3.1.5-1.fc35          updates   94 k
 iwl100-firmware                    noarch 39.31.5.1-131.fc35    updates  137 k
 iwl1000-firmware                   noarch 1:39.31.5.1-131.fc35  updates  247 k
 iwl105-firmware                    noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  216 k
 iwl135-firmware                    noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  224 k
 iwl2000-firmware                   noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  218 k
 iwl2030-firmware                   noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  226 k
 iwl3160-firmware                   noarch 1:25.30.13.0-131.fc35 updates  2.5 M
 iwl3945-firmware                   noarch 15.32.2.9-131.fc35    updates   77 k
 iwl4965-firmware                   noarch 228.61.2.24-131.fc35  updates   90 k
 iwl5000-firmware                   noarch 8.83.5.1_1-131.fc35   updates  361 k
 iwl5150-firmware                   noarch 8.24.2.2-131.fc35     updates  133 k
 iwl6000-firmware                   noarch 9.221.4.1-131.fc35    updates  152 k
 iwl6000g2a-firmware                noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  333 k
 iwl6000g2b-firmware                noarch 18.168.6.1-131.fc35   updates  339 k
 iwl6050-firmware                   noarch 41.28.5.1-131.fc35    updates  291 k
 iwl7260-firmware                   noarch 1:25.30.13.0-131.fc35 updates   15 M
 iwlax2xx-firmware                  noarch 20220411-131.fc35     updates   39 M
 libertas-usb8388-firmware          noarch 2:20220411-131.fc35   updates  101 k
 libipa_hbac                        x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   31 k
 libsolv                            x86_64 0.7.22-1.fc35         updates  403 k
 libsss_autofs                      x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   32 k
 libsss_certmap                     x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   74 k
 libsss_idmap                       x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   36 k
 libsss_nss_idmap                   x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   39 k
 libsss_sudo                        x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   29 k
 linux-firmware                     noarch 20220411-131.fc35     updates  187 M
 linux-firmware-whence              noarch 20220411-131.fc35     updates   48 k
 nspr                               x86_64 4.32.0-6.fc35         updates  137 k
 openexr-libs                       x86_64 3.1.5-1.fc35          updates  1.1 M
 ostree                             x86_64 2022.2-1.fc35         updates  229 k
 ostree-libs                        x86_64 2022.2-1.fc35         updates  424 k
 perl-HTML-Parser                   x86_64 3.78-1.fc35           updates  119 k
 perl-libwww-perl                   noarch 6.62-1.fc35           updates  202 k
 pipewire                           x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates   39 k
 pipewire-alsa                      x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates   62 k
 pipewire-gstreamer                 x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates   59 k
 pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates  135 k
 pipewire-libs                      x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates  1.5 M
 pipewire-pulseaudio                x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates   27 k
 pipewire-utils                     x86_64 0.3.50-1.fc35         updates  325 k
 python3-beautifulsoup4             noarch 4.11.0-1.fc35         updates  134 k
 python3-regex                      x86_64 2022.3.15-1.fc35      updates  347 k
 rsync                              x86_64 3.2.3-9.fc35          updates  388 k
 smartmontools                      x86_64 1:7.3-2.fc35          updates  586 k
 squashfs-tools                     x86_64 4.5.1-1.fc35          updates  226 k
 sssd                               x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   23 k
 sssd-ad                            x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  205 k
 sssd-client                        x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  143 k
 sssd-common                        x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  1.5 M
 sssd-common-pac                    x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   88 k
 sssd-ipa                           x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  268 k
 sssd-kcm                           x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  103 k
 sssd-krb5                          x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   68 k
 sssd-krb5-common                   x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   83 k
 sssd-ldap                          x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates  152 k
 sssd-nfs-idmap                     x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   34 k
 sssd-proxy                         x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   65 k
 sstp-client                        x86_64 1.0.17-1.fc35         updates   67 k
 systemd-container                  x86_64 249.11-1.fc35         updates  523 k
 systemd-oomd-defaults              noarch 249.11-1.fc35         updates   24 k
 systemd-rpm-macros                 noarch 249.11-1.fc35         updates   26 k
     replacing  systemd-rpm-macros.noarch 249.9-1.fc35
 systemd-udev                       x86_64 249.11-1.fc35         updates  1.8 M
     replacing  systemd-udev.x86_64 249.9-1.fc35
 tzdata                             noarch 2022a-2.fc35          updates  432 k
 tzdata-java                        noarch 2022a-2.fc35          updates  156 k
 wavpack                            x86_64 5.4.0-5.fc35          updates  212 k
 xen-libs                           x86_64 4.15.2-3.fc35         updates  637 k
 xen-licenses                       x86_64 4.15.2-3.fc35         updates   49 k
 xfce4-terminal                     x86_64 1.0.0-1.fc35          updates  692 k
 xorg-x11-xinit                     x86_64 1.4.0-14.fc35         updates   55 k
 xz                                 x86_64 5.2.5-9.fc35          updates  214 k
 xz-libs                            x86_64 5.2.5-9.fc35          updates   92 k
Installing dependencies:
 libjose                            x86_64 11-3.fc35             fedora    64 k
 sssd-idp                           x86_64 2.7.0-1.fc35          updates   34 k
Removing:
 kernel                             x86_64 5.16.16-200.fc35      @updates   0  
 kernel-core                        x86_64 5.16.16-200.fc35      @updates  87 M
 kernel-modules                     x86_64 5.16.16-200.fc35      @updates  51 M
 kernel-modules-extra               x86_64 5.16.16-200.fc35      @updates 3.1 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install   6 Packages
Upgrade  93 Packages
Remove    4 Packages

Total download size: 489 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Fedora 35 - x86_64 -209% [=========================================-]  49 kB/s |(1/99): libjose-11-3.fc35.x86_64.rpm            572 kB/s |  64 kB     00:00    
(2/99): kernel-5.16.20-200.fc35.x86_64.rpm      396 kB/s |  86 kB     00:00    
(3/99): openexr-libs-3.1.4-1.fc35_3.1.5-1.fc35. 508 kB/s | 118 kB     00:00    
(4/99): kernel-modules-extra-5.16.20-200.fc35.x 177 kB/s | 3.3 MB     00:18    
(5/99): sssd-idp-2.7.0-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm         36 kB/s |  34 kB     00:00    
(6/99): at-3.2.5-3.fc35.x86_64.rpm               56 kB/s |  61 kB     00:01    
(7/99): kernel-core-5.16.20-200.fc35.x86_64.rpm 1.9 MB/s |  46 MB     00:24    
(8/99): cups-2.3.3op2-17.fc35.x86_64.rpm        391 kB/s | 1.3 MB     00:03    
(9/99): cups-filesystem-2.3.3op2-17.fc35.noarch  16 kB/s |  14 kB     00:00    
(10/99): cups-client-2.3.3op2-17.fc35.x86_64.rp  53 kB/s |  71 kB     00:01    
(11/99): cups-filters-braille-1.28.14-1.fc35.x8  46 kB/s |  38 kB     00:00    
(12/99): cups-filters-libs-1.28.14-1.fc35.x86_6  77 kB/s | 136 kB     00:01    
(13/99): cups-filters-1.28.14-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm 139 kB/s | 770 kB     00:05    
(14/99): cups-libs-2.3.3op2-17.fc35.x86_64.rpm  108 kB/s | 265 kB     00:02    
(15/99): dhcp-client-4.4.3-2.fc35.x86_64.rpm    142 kB/s | 799 kB     00:05    
(16/99): dhcp-common-4.4.3-2.fc35.noarch.rpm     85 kB/s | 126 kB     00:01    
(17/99): distribution-gpg-keys-1.68-1.fc35.noar 121 kB/s | 356 kB     00:02    
(18/99): kernel-modules-5.16.20-200.fc35.x86_64 1.0 MB/s |  51 MB     00:49    
(19/99): cups-ipptool-2.3.3op2-17.fc35.x86_64.r 166 kB/s | 3.9 MB     00:23    
(20/99): fwupd-plugin-flashrom-1.7.7-1.fc35.x86  44 kB/s |  42 kB     00:00    
(21/99): fwupd-plugin-modem-manager-1.7.7-1.fc3  45 kB/s |  71 kB     00:01    
(22/99): fwupd-1.7.7-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm          156 kB/s | 1.9 MB     00:12    
(23/99): gdisk-1.0.9-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm          102 kB/s | 244 kB     00:02    
(24/99): fwupd-plugin-uefi-capsule-data-1.7.7-1 151 kB/s | 2.1 MB     00:14    
(25/99): gzip-1.10-6.fc35.x86_64.rpm             84 kB/s | 149 kB     00:01    
(26/99): imath-3.1.5-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm           62 kB/s |  94 kB     00:01    
(27/99): iwl100-firmware-39.31.5.1-131.fc35.noa  68 kB/s | 137 kB     00:02    
(28/99): iwl1000-firmware-39.31.5.1-131.fc35.no 108 kB/s | 247 kB     00:02    
(29/99): iwl105-firmware-18.168.6.1-131.fc35.no  99 kB/s | 216 kB     00:02    
(30/99): iwl135-firmware-18.168.6.1-131.fc35.no  98 kB/s | 224 kB     00:02    
(31/99): gegl04-0.4.36-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm        161 kB/s | 3.0 MB     00:18    
(32/99): iwl2000-firmware-18.168.6.1-131.fc35.n 100 kB/s | 218 kB     00:02    
(33/99): iwl2030-firmware-18.168.6.1-131.fc35.n 105 kB/s | 226 kB     00:02    
(34/99): iwl3945-firmware-15.32.2.9-131.fc35.no  51 kB/s |  77 kB     00:01    
(35/99): iwl4965-firmware-228.61.2.24-131.fc35.  56 kB/s |  90 kB     00:01    
(36/99): iwl5000-firmware-8.83.5.1_1-131.fc35.n 115 kB/s | 361 kB     00:03    
(37/99): iwl5150-firmware-8.24.2.2-131.fc35.noa  65 kB/s | 133 kB     00:02    

...OMISSIS...

(99/99): ffmpeg-libs-4.4.2-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm    1.3 MB/s | 8.4 MB     00:06    
[DRPM] openexr-libs-3.1.4-1.fc35_3.1.5-1.fc35.x86_64.drpm: done                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           2.1 MB/s | 488 MB     03:56     
Delta RPMs reduced 489.0 MB of updates to 488.1 MB (0.2% saved)
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/bin/coredumpctl from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-veritysetup-generator from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-binfmt.service from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-homed.service from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-homed from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-portabled from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-veritysetup from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/org.freedesktop.portable1.5.gz from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-coredump.8.gz from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.home1.policy from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
  file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.portable1.policy from install of systemd-udev-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
```

EDIT:

The output of `sudo dnf check` is:

```
cryptsetup-libs-2.4.2-1.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with cryptsetup-libs-2.4.3-1.fc35.x86_64
evolution-data-server-3.42.4-1.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with evolution-data-server-3.42.4-2.fc35.x86_64
evolution-data-server-langpacks-3.42.4-1.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with evolution-data-server-langpacks-3.42.4-2.fc35.noarch
libreoffice-data-1:7.2.5.2-6.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with libreoffice-data-1:7.2.6.2-1.fc35.noarch
pam-1.5.2-5.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with pam-1.5.2-7.fc35.x86_64
pcre2-10.37-4.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with pcre2-10.39-1.fc35.x86_64
pcre2-syntax-10.37-4.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with pcre2-syntax-10.39-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-35.15-1.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with selinux-policy-35.16-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-targeted-35.15-1.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with selinux-policy-targeted-35.16-1.fc35.noarch
smartmontools-selinux-1:7.2-11.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with smartmontools-selinux-1:7.3-2.fc35.noarch
systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-libs-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-libs-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-libs-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-libs-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-networkd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-networkd-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-networkd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-networkd-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-pam-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-pam-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-pam-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-pam-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-resolved-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-resolved-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-resolved-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-resolved-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-rpm-macros-249.7-2.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with systemd-rpm-macros-249.9-1.fc35.noarch
systemd-udev-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-udev-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
vim-data-2:8.2.4621-1.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with vim-data-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch
vim-filesystem-2:8.2.4621-1.fc35.noarch is a duplicate with vim-filesystem-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch
Error: Check discovered 24 problem(s)
```

Running `sudo dnf upgrade --allowerasing --best` did not help (same error  as with `sudo dnf update`).

EDIT:

output of `dnf repoquery --duplicates`

```
Fedora 35 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                            4.5 MB/s |  79 MB     00:17    
Fedora 35 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                      2.2 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:01    
Fedora Modular 35 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                    1.9 MB/s | 3.3 MB     00:01    
Fedora 35 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                                                                  4.5 MB/s |  29 MB     00:06    
Fedora Modular 35 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                                                          1.7 MB/s | 2.9 MB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Free                                                                                                                                                                               1.2 MB/s | 934 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Free - Updates                                                                                                                                                                     1.1 MB/s | 401 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Nonfree                                                                                                                                                                            722 kB/s | 239 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Nonfree - Updates                                                                                                                                                                  322 kB/s | 100 kB     00:00    
skype (stable)                                                                                                                                                                                                 20 kB/s | 5.2 kB     00:00    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sat 23 Apr 2022 06:18:21 PM CEST.
cryptsetup-libs-0:2.4.2-1.fc35.x86_64
cryptsetup-libs-0:2.4.3-1.fc35.x86_64
evolution-data-server-0:3.42.4-1.fc35.x86_64
evolution-data-server-0:3.42.4-2.fc35.x86_64
evolution-data-server-langpacks-0:3.42.4-1.fc35.noarch
evolution-data-server-langpacks-0:3.42.4-2.fc35.noarch
libreoffice-data-1:7.2.5.2-6.fc35.noarch
libreoffice-data-1:7.2.6.2-1.fc35.noarch
pam-0:1.5.2-5.fc35.x86_64
pam-0:1.5.2-7.fc35.x86_64
pcre2-0:10.37-4.fc35.x86_64
pcre2-0:10.39-1.fc35.x86_64
pcre2-syntax-0:10.37-4.fc35.noarch
pcre2-syntax-0:10.39-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-0:35.15-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-0:35.16-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-targeted-0:35.15-1.fc35.noarch
selinux-policy-targeted-0:35.16-1.fc35.noarch
smartmontools-selinux-1:7.2-11.fc35.noarch
smartmontools-selinux-1:7.3-2.fc35.noarch
systemd-0:249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-libs-0:249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-libs-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-libs-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-networkd-0:249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-networkd-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-networkd-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-pam-0:249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-pam-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-pam-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-resolved-0:249.11-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-resolved-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-resolved-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
systemd-rpm-macros-0:249.7-2.fc35.noarch
systemd-rpm-macros-0:249.9-1.fc35.noarch
systemd-udev-0:249.7-2.fc35.x86_64
systemd-udev-0:249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
vim-data-2:8.2.4621-1.fc35.noarch
vim-data-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch
vim-filesystem-2:8.2.4621-1.fc35.noarch
vim-filesystem-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch
```

EDIT: I did `sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes` but I am unsure how to deal with this:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:48 ago on Sun 24 Apr 2022 01:39:51 PM CEST.
Installed package systemd-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package systemd-udev-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package systemd-libs-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package systemd-rpm-macros-249.9-1.fc35.noarch not available.
Installed package systemd-networkd-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package systemd-pam-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package systemd-resolved-249.11-1.fc35.x86_64 not available.
Installed package vim-data-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch not available.
Installed package vim-filesystem-2:8.2.4701-1.fc35.noarch not available.
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: systemd, systemd-udev
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange error. What it's saying is that some of the files from the update to package `systemd-udev` to version `249.11-1.fc35.x86_64` won't work with the `systemd` version on the system which is `systemd-249.7-2.fc35.x86_64`.

But, `systemd-udev` is a subpackage of `systemd`, which means that it should be part of the same update transaction. Why isn't it trying to update that? Your updated question shows the answer: the system is in a bad state to start for some reason, and there are duplicates of the `systemd` package installed.

The `sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes` command (a synonym for `dnf remove --cleandups) usually should fix this — even for protected packages. I'm a little perplexed that you're getting that error.

I believe the following sequence (documented in the `dnf` man page) should work:

```
$ sudo dnf shell
> config protected_packages dnf
> remove --duplicates
> upgrade
> transaction run
```

**HOWEVER**, there is a non-zero chance that this will actually remove systemd and make it so your system won't boot. Watch carefully what it wants to do before saying `Y` to the prompt when you get to that after this sequence. It *should* have a `Reinstalling` section, and that should mention replacing systemd packages. If it does not, don't say `Y` — we'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: I posted the complete output...

Comment: Okay, so, the mystery is: why isn't it trying to upgrade `systemd` to `249.11-1.fc35.x86_64`? I think it might be that you have _two_ versions of that package installed from some prior problem. Can you run `dnf check`, please? What does that say?

Comment: It may be that `sudo dnf upgrade --allowerasing --best` will clean this up, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have run ```sudo dnf check```

Comment: Think there is a failed transaction, and duplicate systemd packages are installed. You need to remove the duplicates. Check with: `dnf repoquery --duplicates`

Comment: I tried that command (posted above) but I don't know how to go from there...

Comment: `package-cleanup —cleandupes`

Comment: It still gives an error (written above)